# when: manual in downstream pipeline causes upstream to report failure

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using a multi-project pipeline to separate my end to end tests from my main application code. My end of end tests, if I run the full suite, can take a significant amount of time. I’ve nicely broken them into various groupings using `pytest` and it’s `mark` feature.

I’d like to be able to run specific scenarios from within the pipeline now by setting each of these different scenarios to `when: manual` . Unfortunately, as soon as I add this, the child pipeline reports it has failed to the parent and progress stops. I can manually run each section, as expected, but even then success is not reported back to the parent pipeline.

[image: GitLab Pipeline Example]

This is an example of the pipeline. The `Integration Tests` step has reported a failure, and I’ve manually run the `Fast Tests` from the downstream pipeline. It has passed, and as the only job in the pipeline the entire downstream pipeline passes. Yet the parent still reports failure so `Deploy` doesn’t get run.

If I remove `when: manual` from the downstream pipeline, `Integration Tests` will run the full test suite, pass, and `Deploy` will move on as expected.

This is the parent project pipeline.

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./src
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"

stages:
  - Static Analysis
  - Local Tests
  - Integration Tests
  - Deploy

mypy:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
    - mypy .

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
    - flake8 --max-line-length=88

pytest-smoke:
  stage: Local Tests
  script:
    - pytest -m smoke

pytest-unit:
  stage: Local Tests
  script:
    - pytest -m unittest

pytest-slow:
  stage: Local Tests
  script:
    - pytest -m slow

pytest-fast:
  stage: Local Tests
  script:
    - pytest -m fast

int-tests:
  stage: Integration Tests
  trigger:
    project: andy/gitlab-integration-testing-integration-tests
    strategy: depend

deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deployed!"
```

The end to end tests pipeline looks like this:

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - python --version
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./src
  - python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"

stages:
  - Fast Tests

pytest-smoke:
  stage: Fast Tests
  when: manual
  script:
    - pytest -m smoke
```

How can I selectively (manually) run downstream jobs and report success back to the parent pipeline? Without `when: manual` in that last step on the end to end (downstream) pipeline it performs exactly as I want. But, in the real world pipeline I have, I don’t want to run the end to end tests on everything. Usually it is selected scenarios.

I am currently running: GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.2.2-ee